# 2 Wordpress containers in Docker but just works only one

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to make 2 different and independent WordPress sites, in 2 differents docker containers.

I have 2 Docker Containers of WordPress in 2 different folders but the thing is that the first one (Container 1) works fine but the second (Container 2) does not work, it shows me `Error establishing a database connection`

Container 1

```
services:
  db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:8.0.27
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somewordpress
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
      - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress
    expose:
      - 3306
      - 33060
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password    
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - 8084:80
    restart: always
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
    volumes: 
      - ./html:/var/www/html 
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

Container 2

```
services:
  db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:8.0.27
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somewordpress
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress2
      - MYSQL_USER=wordpress2
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress2
    expose:
      - 3306
      - 33060
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8081:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password    
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - 8085:80
    restart: always
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress2
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wordpress2
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress2
    volumes: 
      - ./html:/var/www/html 
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Both your database servers are using the same port. Change on of them and let each container connect to its respective server on a different port

Comment: I changed the database ports but it shows me the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can run two independent Wordpress websites simultaneously using just one `docker-compose.yml` file if you always wanted to run them together.

If you still want to run them as two containers, you should be able to spit this `docker-compose.yml` into two separate yml files and will work the same.

Here is a tested working `docker-compose.yml` setup...

```yml
version: '3.7'

services:
  
  # site 1 database
  db_1:
    image: mysql:5.7
    networks:
      - wordpress_1
    volumes:
      # persist site 1 volume mapping for database
      - ./site-1/db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
  
  # site 1 wordpress
  wordpress_1:
    depends_on:
      - db_1
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      # persist site 1 volume mapping for files
      - ./site-1/themes/example:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/example:delegated
      - ./site-1/mu-plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/mu-plugins
      - ./site-1/plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
      - ./site-1/uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
      - ./site-1/logs:/var/www/html/wp-content/logs
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - ./error-logging.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error-logging.ini
    networks:
      - wordpress_1
    ports:
      - '8001:80'
    restart: always
    environment:
      # dev debug mode
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
      # docker wp config settings for site 1
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db_1
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
        
        if(!defined('WP_HOME')) {
          /* force our home url for site 1 */
          define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost:8001');
          define('WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME);
        }

  # site 2 database
  db_2:
    image: mysql:5.7
    networks:
      - wordpress_2
    volumes:
      # persist site 2 volume mapping for database
      - ./site-2/db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  # site 2 wordpress
  wordpress_2:
    depends_on:
      - db_2
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      # persist site 2 volume mapping for files
      - ./site-2/themes/example:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/example:delegated
      - ./site-2/mu-plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/mu-plugins
      - ./site-2/plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
      - ./site-2/uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
      - ./site-2/logs:/var/www/html/wp-content/logs
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - ./error-logging.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error-logging.ini
    networks:
      - wordpress_2
    ports:
      - '8002:80'
    restart: always
    environment:
      # dev debug mode
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
      # docker wp config settings for site 2
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db_2
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
        
        if(!defined('WP_HOME')) {
          /* force our home url for site 2 */
          define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost:8002');
          define('WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME);
        }

networks:
  wordpress_1:
  wordpress_2:
```

You might not even need the networks bit, though not sure how it will run with out i'll let you test.

All you got to do is simply run `docker-compose up -d`

That will then create two independent local wordpress installations with persistent volume mapping to local folders `site-1` and `site-2`...

[image]

Here is what it looks like in docker desktop when running...

[image]

Then you access the wordpress websites at these ports...

1. http://localhost:8001/ (site 1)
2. http://localhost:8002/ (site 2)

Before running `docker-compose up -d` you must create two `.ini` files in the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml` file...

**`uploads.ini`**

```
file_uploads = On
memory_limit = 2000M
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
post_max_size = 2000M
max_execution_time = 600
```

**`error-logging.ini`**

```
error_reporting = E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_WARNING | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR ^ E_DEPRECATED
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
error_log = /var/www/html/wp-content/logs/debug.log
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = On
ignore_repeated_source = Off
html_errors = Off
```

Now you have these three project files, you are ready to run `docker-compose up -d`

Every time you `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up -d`, you installation setup and data will be the same.